# Retrieve screen name from twitter account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-rest-api

Is it possible to get a twitter account's username from an instance of the Twitter REST client?  Specifically, I would like to get the name for the twitter account associated with the client's access tokens and secrets.

I searched through the [twitter gem documentation on rubydoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Users) and looked at the [Twitter API user object documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object) but wasn't able to solve the problem.  I did try using `client.attributes`, `client.to_h` and `client.screen_name`, but received an unknown method error.

For context, I'm currently working on a twitter bot that auto-replies to hashtags when it is looped into a conversation.  We want to prevent the bot from tweeting at itself, so we are currently hard-coding in the bot name as an account not to tweet at.  It would be helpful if we could replace the hard-coded name with something like `client.account_name`.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the documentation for the `client` object of the twitter gem says it has a `user` method (Methods included from Users section) [1]. The documentation for the `user` method states it returns a `Twitter::User` object of the currently authenticated user [2]. This class inherits from `BasicUser` which is where the `screen_name` method exists [3].

```
client.user.screen_name
```

1. http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Client
2. http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Users#user-instance_method
3. http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/BasicUser

Answer (score 0):

You say

> I would like to get the name for the twitter account associated with the client's access tokens and secrets

and

> We want to prevent the bot from tweeting at itself, so we are currently hard-coding in the bot name as an account not to tweet at.

If I understand you correctly, you want to find out which application was used to send a tweet - so you can filter it out?

In each tweet, you will find an attribute called `source`.  This shows which app the user sent the tweet with.

For example,

```
"created_at": "Sun Mar 11 11:25:05 +0000 2018",
"source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e",
"in_reply_to_status_id_str": "972414342166654976",
```

That Tweet was sent using Twitter for Android's API keys.

And in this example:

```
"source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/shkspr.mobi\/blog\/tag\/solar\/\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eEdent's Solar Panels\u003c\/a\u003e",
"in_reply_to_status_id": null,
```

The Tweet was sent from my personal API key.

Give your API key a unique name and URL.  When you retrieve Tweets, check the `source` parameter, and don't reply to any which have been sent using your access token and secret.